# What does this sign mean in the definition of triangulated categories?

Tags: notation, category-theory, definition, triangulated-categories

I have two questions about [Wikipedia's definition of triangulated categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#Definition).

1. One of the axioms for distinguished triangles (TR 2) says that if $X\overset u\to Y \overset v\to Z \overset w\to X[1]$ is a distinguished triangle, then so are $Y \overset v\to Z \overset w\to X[1] \overset{-u[1]}\longrightarrow Y[1]$ and $Z[-1]\overset{-w[-1]}\longrightarrow X \overset u\to Y \overset v \to Z$. I get that the translation functor defines $u[1]$ and $w[-1]$, but what does the minus sign in $-u[1]$ and $-w[-1]$ mean?
2. In TR 1, what does the final "$\to \cdot$" mean? Is it the same as a final "$\to $" as used in the definition of a triangle three lines further up?

Question 2 is really just a PS (I assume that the answer is an affirmative, because what else could it be?). It's question 1 that has me wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a triangulated category, the morphism sets are actually vector spaces over a base field (or modules over a base ring, depending on your level of generality).  Hence $-u[1]$ is the morphism $u[1]$ multiplied by the scalar $-1$.

As for your second question, the arrow is what you expect in a triangle.  If you wish to be precise, you could write $X\to X\to 0 \to X[1]$.

Comment: The hom-sets in an additive category are abelian groups. I'm just blind.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to add a small question to this answer: what is the "meaning" of such a minus sign? I mean, why is it there, and what would be unpleasant without it? Thanks in advance :)